# IBM 8183 (P4-1Gb) ThinkCentre BIOS locked by keyboard absence

Tags: bios, thinkcentre

I converted this old machine to MineCraft server with MineOS for my son (12) ~ set BIOS to run system without keyboard and mouse ~ now on reboot the BIOS stops: 'no keyboard' error (!) ~ i can't get into the BIOS now, not even with an old keyboard attached.

Answer (score 0):

Power down the system, open the system, remove the small "watch-like" battery (Or find the BIOS reset jumper and short it out momentarily) and then replace to normal configuration.

This will reset your bios to factory settings. Try again. This time, instead of disabling your mouse/keyboard, look for a `Stop on Error` setting normally located at the bottom of the first page. "Phenox BIOS"

Comment: this worked, could enter bios. :) No 'Halt on no error' in this bios :(